# Which software have this guy used to make this video?

Tags: video-editor, stop-motion

I'd like to do something similar. I don't know if its a stop motion or a animation.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it involves hand-drawn animation and some compositing of photos. You could do that in-camera, by physically drawing on paper and moving photos around by hand, and shooting it frame-by-frame, or you could do it in a compositing application. There are many compositing applications to choose from, one of the most commonly used is Adobe After effects.